# MySQL Connection Error on Apache Port 8080

Tags: mysql, apache

I am running IIS on default port and Apache on 8080 on Windows 2000 server. Both run fine, however, I am unable to establish connection to the MySQL server. It gives me the following error

> **Access denied for user 'root@localhost' < using password: YES >**

I am pretty sure am using the right password. My question is do I need to change MySQL configuration settings since am using Apache on a different port ?

Comment: you should check port in mysql configuration file.

Comment: well the MySQL port is 3306. I don't think I need to change that, do I?

Comment: try including your port in login e.g. root@localhost:8080

Comment: @Shayan Husaini How do I do that?

Comment: are you trying to access from command prompt?

Comment: you need to change the default port of your iis server to 8081 or anyone you like.

Answer (score 2):

Try reseting the password. Open a console and type:

```
mysqladmin -u root password your-new-password
mysql -u root -p
```

Then you'll be prompted to input the new password.

Answer (score 0):

The root user has a default password which is an empty space. At times this causes connection problems.

I would recommend that you create a user other than the root, and ensure that they have a password then you can use the new username and password instead.

Comment: But I guess to create a new user I first need to be successfully logged in, right?

Comment: You can create the user at the shell, see next answer below. You have two options: either reset root password or create a new user, Resetting root password may be easier for the start but you need to create a different user later on for additional secuirty.